# PHP -- Can't view image after uploading it to created directory

Tags: php, image-uploading, file-permissions

After looking through several posts on here and as well as Google, I've yet to find a solution to my problem. I'm making a website where a user can upload images. If no personal directory exists for their images, I create one and place the image inside. The issue is that after the directory is made and the image is inside, I can't view it because I don't have the correct permissions once I navigate to that folder and try to open it. I've seen several people with the same issue, and none of the solutions I've found worked for me.

I'm aware I need to check things like size, type, if it already exists, etc. At this point, I'm just trying to see the image.

**EDIT**: Changed permissions from 0777 to 0755, but the issue remains. 
**EDIT2**: fileperms returns 33206 when run on the uploaded image.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
    {
        $path = "images/$user_id";

        if(!file_exists($path))
        {
            mkdir($path, 0755, true);
        }

        $target_dir = "$path/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) 
        {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
        {
            chmod($path . "/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], 0755); 
            echo "The file was upload successfully.";   
        }
        else
        {
            echo "There was an error with the upload.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: directory permission should be set to `0755` not `0777`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made those changes, but I am still unable to view the image.

Comment: So when you upload it you can see that the file has been uploaded to the folder?

Comment: Yes, the image is in the folder, but when I try to open it, I'm told I don't have the correct permissions to view it.

Comment: How are you trying to 'see' it exactly? Its not clear in your code example.

Comment: When I navigate to the created directory, I open the images/$user_id folder. Inside, the image file they uploaded is there. When I try to open it with Photos, it tells me I don't have permission to view this file.

Comment: Are you viewing this locally or on a server?

Comment: I am viewing it locally.

Comment: Try not setting the permissions and just do `mkdir($path);`...don't know if that'll work honestly but try it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this and is having the same problem, the issue is that the temporary folder that the file is placed in has permissions that prevent you viewing it. I solved this by editing my php.ini file, and setting the upload_tmp_dir to some folder I made of my desktop with full permissions.